# Are HTTP libraries useful for HTTP-like server / client application?

Tags: c++, http

I am engaged in a project which develops server and client that behaves very much similar to HTTP server and client.

- For HTTP, the server is actually a file server. The server sends a file to the client.
- For my project, the client sends a file to the server and server just responds to the client with an analysis result for the file.
- And my project and the HTTP1.0(maybe not HTTP1.1) both are stateless.

So both are very much same, `except that the file transfer direction is in the opposite way`.
But even with the HTTP, the client can send files to the server with `POST message`?!

So I all of a sudden came to a question that we can just use HTTP libraries instead we develop everything from scratch.

I searched about HTTP libraries in stackoverflow.

[mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/), [pion](https://github.com/cloudmeter/pion)

There exist these above.

In my case, can I just apply one of these HTTP libraries for my project instead of reinventing the whole?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Http Libraries are a good fit for what you want to do, and they're usually referred to as [Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).

There is also a design methodology called [RESTful web-services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).  If you follow these guidelines when designing your services, 3rd party tools such as Chrome's [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) can help the development process.

I don't know if C++ is an absolute must for you, but if not - I highly recommend the [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net/) framework which will take practically all the legwork out of writing these things.

Answer (score 1):

Never ever rewrite or recreate existing protocols like HTTP which have already done most of the work for you. You can do most of what you need in HTTP and probably much much more.

If you are building in C++, I can recommend using POCO C++ libraries (http://pocoproject.org/), it comes with built in HTTP Server/Client that can be used to most things you need pretty easily and portably in most architectures.